# Vee Validate 3.0 custom classes not applied

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

From the docs, I think I need to use configure to add custom classes to my validated fields, but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have so far...

```
import { extend, configure, localize } from 'vee-validate'
import { required, min, max } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import en from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en.json'

// Install rules
extend('required', required)
extend('min', min)
extend('max', max)

// Install classes
configure({
  classes: {
    valid: 'is-valid',
    invalid: 'is-invalid'
  }
})

// Install messages
localize({
  en
})
```

And in my view....

```
<ValidationObserver ref="observer" v-slot="{ invalid }" tag="form" @submit.prevent="checkRef()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reference">Reference</label>
    <ValidationProvider rules="required|max:20" name="reference" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input maxlength="20" name="reference" v-model="ref" id="reference" class="form-control"/>
      <span class="warning">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </div>
  <button @click="checkRef" class="btn btn-primary app-button">Check Reference</button>
</ValidationObserver>
```

When I click the button, I see the error message but I don't get the 'in-invalid' class applied to my field.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VeeValidate does not apply the classes automatically anymore, since `v3` you now must bind it yourself. Like `errors` you can extract `classes` from the slot props and apply it to your input:

```html
<ValidationProvider rules="required|max:20" name="reference" v-slot="{ errors, classes }">
  <input maxlength="20" name="reference" v-model="ref" id="reference" class="form-control" :class="classes" />
  <span class="warning">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now! I need the code you've given here but I can use the configure code to override the class names. Thanks as always logaretm